# What's the best way to replace eval?

Tags: javascript

I deal with a JavaScript code to improve.
The idea here is to invoke functions dynamically.

Here is the code to replace:

```
//this.actionCallback return the name of the function to invoke
eval(this.actionCallback + "('testArgument')");
```

What is the best way to replace it:

This way:

```
window[this.actionCallback]("testArgument");
```

Or this way:

```
var actionToCall = this.actionCallback+'("testArgument");';
var functionToInvoke = new Function(actionToCall);
functionToInvoke();
```

Or is there is a better way to do this?

Comment: This makes no sense what-so-ever. Why do you need any of these things? Why can't you just call this.actionCallback('testArgument')?

If 'this.actionCallback' is a string, well then (it shouldn't be for one, it should just reference the callback) if your trying to send in dynamic parameters from diffren't stages of your code, you can use a partial function application. If you REALLY want to reference functions by a string, you can place those functions in any object, not necessarily the window object, and then call them.

Comment: @Greg Agnew The client receives this action name from the server under a string representation. What du you mean by "use a partial function application"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function Its essentially the method of creating a reference to a function where one, two, or all of the parameters are predefined, such that the new 'partial' function can be called at a later state and the non-predefined parameters can then be added. It's not suitable for what you've now described. If your simply receiving a string from the server that specifies a function, just put those functions in an object and call object['functionname']();

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/ Although the original link I gave is the logical definition, here is an article by Mr Resig that is in javascript, (probably more helpful..)

Answer (score 4):

The first way is a much better method - `new Function(actionToCall)` is just eval in disguise.

Comment: new Function is evil if it's treated as a temporary function. If your using it to create permanent functions then your either doing it wrong or pushing the limits of what you should be using JavaScript for.(try LISP instead)

Answer (score 2):

Both of the alternatives you have mentioned are **not equivalent** to the first one:

- Your first alternative requires that the function name be the member of `window` (in other words, defined at global scope). Having a function inside another scope will cause this to fail, but it doesn't use eval. :)
- Your second alternative creates a function object using the `Function()` constructor, so this also only works when the function in declared at the global scope, because [a function defined by a Function constructor does not inherit any scope other than the global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope), and as said in Jamie Wong's answer, using the Function() constructor is still considered as eval :(

Here is an alternative that should work like your first one, but looks slightly better, but still uses eval.

```
eval(this.actionCallback)("testArgument");
```

But the best way is that `this.actionCallback` should **be a real function object**, and not just a function's name, then you can call:

```
this.actionCallback("testArgument");
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting that `this.actionCallback` should be an actual function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `window[this.actionCallback]("testArgument");`.

This way there is no `eval`ing or making anonymous functions.  You are just calling the function directly.

Answer (score 0):

In case like this you probably do not want to allow calling arbitrary functions, only "action" functions.
Build a list of supported callbacks

```
actionCallbacks["doWork"] = doWork;
```

Call them

```
actionCallbacks[this.actionCallback]("testArgument")
```

And catch if function does not exist

Answer (score 0):

If the function belongs to an object you can do something like this:

```
function run(func, object, args = []) {
  object[func]().apply(object, args);
}
```

Also, here is unique (but not very reliable) way of replacing eval:

```
function evaluate(code) {
  location.href = "javascript:" + code;
}

evaluate("alert(1)");
```

Comment: +1 for the first part of the answer, -1 for the second. That `evaluate` function is just causing unnecessary confusion, with no advantage over normal `eval`.

Comment: @Bergi Yes I know it is not a very good way to replace eval but in some cases, it may work for people (but probably not).